# json fieldnames spaces

Tags: javascript, json, spaces

I've such a json structure:

```
info:
{
First Name: "Robert",
Last Name: "Smith"
}
```

I'm tring to point to data with javascript using something like: "info.First Name"
I know it's incorrect.
How can I retrieve those information from the structure I have?

thank

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That's not valid JSON.  JSON is a data transport format that requires field names to be string delimited with *double quotes*, e.g.

```
{
    "info" : {
        "First Name": "Robert",
        "Last Name": "Smith"
    }
}
```

After parsing, you can then use `obj.info["First Name"]` to access the First Name field.

What you have is a JS object literal (that's still invalid), but you can apply the same technique (stringify the property names) to reach the same end goal.

Comment: +1 Specifically, the JSON property names must be delimited with *double* quotes (not single quotes, which would be valid in JavaScript) in the JSON text.

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle to mess around with this https://jsfiddle.net/cgjerdingen/f2kn5x59/