# Parsing JSON properties with spaces into objects

Tags: json, json.net

I'm working with a third party system that returns JSON.

I'm trying to work out how to deserialise the following json;

```
{"getResponse": {
    "Results": {
        "Result 1": {"Row": [{Name:Somename}]
     }
}
```

I'm using the Newtonsoft JSON library. Anyone know how I can parse this into .Net objects?

Comment: typically you'd use `obj['Result 1']` instead of `obj->Result 1`, whatever the equivalent would be in your chosen .net lang.

Comment: This is invalid JSON (maybe just a "typo" in the question?)

Comment: No this is not a typo. The field names are in quotes and valid.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716792/json-fieldnames-spaces

Comment: Is there some fixed set of results, or could there be any number of them?

Comment: Here is a useful website for analyzing json. http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ You can see it does not like your snippet. Are you generating this json or is it being provided from an external source?

Comment: Fixed. One field named 'Result 1'. Within this there is the Row array.

Comment: This is being provided by an external source I don't have control over.  Fiddler thinks this is valid

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ also complains.  `Name:Somename` needs to be `"Name": "Somename"`.  Also, there needs to be an `} }` at the end to match the opening and closing curly braces.

Comment: If your JSON were valid, this would be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536533/how-can-i-parse-a-json-string-that-would-cause-illegal-c-sharp-identifiers

Comment: I omitted the exact json because it is too long.  you are correct I missed a closing brace.  Also, the name field should be enclosed in quotes as pointed out.  However, the space is valid and the answer to that question does not help.

Comment: Currently I can access the list I am interested in like this JObject result = JObject.Parse(jobStatusResponse1);
            dynamic t = result["getResponse"]["Results"]["Result 1"]["Row"];
However, I still cannot parse the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To parse your JSON into objects using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` you can make your class structure like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public GetResponse getResponse { get; set; }
}

public class GetResponse
{
    public Results Results { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
    [JsonProperty("Result 1")]
    public Result1 Result1 { get; set; }
}

public class Result1
{
    [JsonProperty("Row")]
    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize like this:

```
string json = @"
{
    ""getResponse"": {
        ""Results"": {
            ""Result 1"": {
                ""Row"": [
                    {
                        ""Name"": ""Somename""
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}";

RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
foreach (Row row in root.getResponse.Results.Result1.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope there's a better way of doing this so I'm posting this in the hope someone will provide a better answer.

Given the below (corrected) JSON;

```
{"getResponse": {
    "Results": {
        "Result 1": {"Row": [{"Name":"Somename"}]
     }
  }
}
```

I want to deserialize the elements in the Row array and not sure how to do this with a custom converter.

So my solution till I have the time to find a better way is this;

```
JObject result = JObject.Parse(response);
var t = result["getResponse"]["Results"]["Result 1"]["Row"];
var els =                 
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyResponse>>(t.ToString());
```

Comment: However, what I would like to do is user the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> method.  However, I'm not sure what class structure I would need for the given JSON.